# Update database method in .net

Tags: c#, ado.net

I'm trying to update the database using a method were the parameters of the method will be used rather then using an SQL statement. I did this so a user can enter information into the database.

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection con;
DataSet dsl;
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter da;

public String updateDatabase(int id, String Fname, String Lname, int age, string job)
{
    con = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\Owner\\Documents\\CIS3052.mdb";
    dsl = new DataSet();

    da = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter();

    con.Open();

    DataRow dRow = dsl.Tables["Employee"].NewRow();
    dRow["ID"] = id;
    dRow["Fname"] = Fname;
    dRow["Lname"] = Lname;
    dRow["Age"] = age;
    dRow["Job"] = job;
    dsl.Tables["Employee"].Rows.Add(dRow);

    da.Update(dsl, "Employee");
    return null;
}
```

The problem I have is in this line:

```
DataRow dRow = dsl.Tables["Employee"].NewRow();
```

It is telling me:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I tried using `da.Fill()` but I cannot find a way to use that without using a SQL statement.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `dsl.Tables["Employee"]` dose not exist. Once you fill `dsl.Tables["Employee"]` with `da.Fill()` then it become available.

Once you called

```
DataRow dRow = dsl.Tables["Employee"].NewRow();
```

You are trying to access the "Employee" table in dataset, but dataset does not know about `Employee` table until you tell it (by calling `da.Fill()`).

IMO there is no way to call `DataRow dRow = dsl.Tables["Employee"].NewRow();` without filling it.

Comment: So if I have to use the sql insert, how will I do the statement to accept the parameters of the method instead of having to add pre set data.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8.aspx  Command text can be stored procedure or sql statement. In case of sql statement all the parameters must be define with @ in sql statement. var SQL = "update myTable Set myColumn = @columevalue". Now you need to add a sql parameter in command object with @columevalue.

Answer (score 1):

It is because there is nothing in your dataset. Check your code there.

Answer (score 0):

This is becuase you don´t have any table called Employee in you dataset. This is a very complicated to update record in a database. You might try the SQLCommand  class instead

```
string sql= "Build you query";
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
               "your connectionstring"))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
            sql, connection);
        connection.Open();


        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        reader.Close();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must first fill the dataset.

Untested, but worth trying:

```
con.Open();
da = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter();
da.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand("Employee", con);
da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.TableDirect;
da.Fill(dsl);
```

Choosing `CommandType.TableDirect` should bring you the whole table without using whole SQL statement.

Comment: Debug and see the value of `dsl.Tables.Count` - what you have there?